# How to format number as time in Moment?

Tags: javascript, momentjs, angular-moment

I am using [bs-datepicker](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/datepickers) for save time as number in mongodb. In mongodb, it has **time** field with value i.e, `38700000` and `41400000` which are `16.15` and `17.00` respectively.

Now, i want to format the above time in readable form. I am using `moment 2.16`. Here i try but unable to do [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ua94tf40/1/)

```
console.log(moment.unix(38700000).format('HH:mm')) //03:30, expect:16:15
console.log(moment.unix(41400000).format('HH:mm')) //09:30, expect:17:00
```

And, how to convert from **HH:mm** to number. e.g `18:71` convert into number

Comment: When I run `console.log(moment(38700000).format('HH:mm'));` & `console.log(moment(41400000).format('HH:mm'));` I get the values 10:45 and 11:30, respectively. These are both 5:30 mins away from your target values, so I would make sure your time zones are correct (probably best to use UTC+0). You can pass `x` as a format argument to get a unix timestamp from a date.

Comment: I also want to point out that moment.unix(t) takes a unix timestamp in seconds, whereas moment(t) takes a unix timestamp in milliseconds.

Comment: @SamJudge, thanks for reply. My timezone is +5:30 GMT so, how to implement it?

Comment: Simple, use .local() before .format() `console.log(moment(38700000).local().format('HH:mm'))` :) I see you're using mongo, so what is probably happening is you are uploading in your local time format, mongo stores it as UTC, and you are getting the UTC value back when you are expecting the local time. Doing the above should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data you have is in terms of milliseconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000 UTC.

```
38700000 == 1970-01-01T10:45:00Z
41400000 == 1970-01-01T11:30:00Z
```

If you *convert* those to the time zone offset you mentioned in comments (UTC+05:30) then the time portion of the values line up to what you expected.

```
38700000 == 1970-01-01T10:45:00Z == 1970-01-01T16:15:00+05:30
41400000 == 1970-01-01T11:30:00Z == 1970-01-01T17:00:00+05:30
```

Your values don't align at all, because you are using moment's `unix` function, which expects time in seconds, not milliseconds (because [Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) is in whole seconds unless otherwise specified).

Also, by relying on the local time zone, you may get different values than expected if the user is in a different time zone.

The correct way to get what you asked for is:

```
moment(38700000).utcOffset("+05:30").format("HH:mm") // "16:15"
moment(41400000).utcOffset("+05:30").format("HH:mm") // "17:00"
```

Do recognize though that this means your original data is not stored with reference to UTC, but with reference to UTC+05:30.  It would be better if you had stored UTC-based values instead, so you would do:

```
moment.utc(58500000).format("HH:mm") // "16:15"
moment.utc(61200000).format("HH:mm") // "17:00"
```

Of course, the real problem here is that you're storing a time-of-day into a date-time field.  Probably the best thing to do would to not use the `Date` type at all in your MongoDB data, but rather just store the string `"16:15"` or the equivalent number of total minutes as an integer (60 * 16 + 15 == 975).

Comment: thank for brief example. The last paragraph is awesome that is good way.